# What is the right syntax to return an array from a method/function C#

Tags: c#, arrays

I'm doing an assignment where the I should store some string data in arrays. Each new string should be stored in a separate array, that's why I need a method that returns a new array with a name given from a user. **What I want is a new array with a uniq name each time I call this method.**

On the 2d line I get an error: A local or parameter named '_arrayNameFromUser' cannot be declared in this scope because that name is used in an enclosing local scope to define a local or parameter    test

So how do I create a new array with a user-specified name?

```
A local or parameter named '_arrayNameFromUser' cannot be declared in this scope because that name is used in an enclosing local scope to define a local or parameter   test
```

```
static string[] NewArary(string arrayNameFromUser)
    {            
        string[] arrayNameFromUser = new string[2];

        return arrayNameFromUser;
    }
```

Comment: You already have variable named `_arrayNameFromUser` in the method body - it's a method parameter. So you cannot declare another variable with exactly same name.

Comment: Also note, that in mode code guidelines, `_` would indicate a private instance field and not a local variable or method parameter

Comment: @Icepickle changed that, thanks

Comment: Can you add the precise description of your assignment? I think _(like some of the others)_ there is a misconception here.

Answer (score 4):

Give it a different name than the parameter:

```
static string[] NewArary(string name)
{            
    string[] ret = new string[2];
    ret[0] = name;
    return ret;
}
```

Note that C# naming conventions only use `_underscorePrefixed` names for fields, not parameters or locals, and often it's restricted to only `static` fields too (as instance fields can be accessed with `this.`), see the below example of conventional capitalization of identifiers:

```
public class TypeName
{
    private static readonly String _staticField = "foo";

    private Int32 field;

    public Int32 Property { get { return this.field; } }

    public const String PublicConstant = "bar";

    public void Method(Uri parameter) {

        Int32 local = 123;
    }
}
```

(Though my use of `Int32` instead of `int` and `String` instead of `string` is a controversial stance :D)

Comment: This is wrong because it will simply return an array with name "ret" and with first element name (containing what a user have entered). What I want is a new array with a uniq name each time I call this method.

Comment: @Gusto You cannot do that - compiled code is static and fixed, including identifiers. You cannot parameterise variable names like that. I think you misunderstand your programming assignment.

Answer (score 2):

You've got some confusion here between compile time/runtime. You don't create new variables at runtime.

I *suspect* that what you need is a `Dictionary<string,string[]>`. Then, instead of calling `NewArary` (sic), you'd instead do:

```
Dictionary<string,string[]> arrays = new Dictionary<string,string[]>();

//NewArary("abc");
arrays.Add("abc", new string[]{});
```

And then later you'd obtain the `abc` array by doing:

```
var thatArray = arrays["abc"];
```

Comment: I cannot use dictionary, I MUST use arrays ONLY (this is an academic assignment)

Comment: @Gusto - then you've somewhere misunderstood your assignment since you *can't* create new "variables" at runtime.